# 数式をJavascriptから読み込んでHTML上に表示させたい(MathML+MathJax)

Tags: javascript, html, html5

MathMLという、数式をWEB上で表示するマークアップ言語を
Javascriptから呼び出してHTML上で使用したいのですが、うまく行きません。

Javascript側で以下のような関数を作って

```
function displayText()
{
    var str = "<math>";
    str += "<mi>i</mi>";
    str += "</math>";

    var elem = document.getElementById("test");
    elem.innerHTML = str;
}
```

HTML側でボタンを押して以下のように呼び出しをします。

```
<div id="test"></div>
<input type="button" value="MathML" onclick="displayText()">
```

すると、本来、以下のようにカッコいい数式用の「i」の文字が表示されるはずなのに
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

実際には以下のような普通の「i」しか表示されません。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Javascriptを使用した時のみこの問題が起きていて
普通にMathML+MathJaxを使ってもこの問題は起きません。
何か私のJavascriptやHTMLの使い方がおかしいのでしょうか？

以下にサンプルのHTMLファイルをアップロードしました。

・こちらがJavascriptを使った場合のサンプルです。
　ボタンを押すと、普通の「i」のみ表示されます。
https://github.com/pekochun/test/blob/master/JavascriptWithMathML.html

・こちらがJavascriptを使わずにMathMLを直に書いた場合のサンプルです。
　ボタンを押す前から、カッコいい「i」が表示されます。
https://github.com/pekochun/test/blob/master/NoJavascriptMathML.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MathJaxのスクリプトは、ページを読み込んだ際にページのHTML中のMathML要素をかっこいい表示に変換します。
ということは、JavaScriptで後からページにMathML要素を追加してもMathJaxによる処理が行われません。
これが、ご提示のサンプルでかっこいい数式が表示されない理由です。

後から追加したMathML要素をMathJaxに処理してもらうには、[MathJax.Hub.Typeset](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/api/hub.html#Typeset)を用いるとよいようです。
具体的には以下のようにすると求める動作になりました。

```
<html>
<head>
  <script async="" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.2/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function displayText()
  {
    var str = "<math>";
    str += "<mi>i</mi>";
    str += "</math>";

    var elem = document.getElementById("test");
    elem.innerHTML = str;

    // elemの中身をMathJaxに処理してもらう
    MathJax.Hub.Typeset(elem);
  }
  </script> 
</head>
<body>
  <div id="test"></div>
  <input type="button" value="MathML" onclick="displayText()">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

MathJaxを動的に使うには

```
MathJax.Hub.Typeset()
```

を利用する必要があります。
書き換えはなかなか重いのでターゲット要素を指定して実行したりしましょう。
https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v1.0/typeset.html